# Unique Student id Count between Two table who borrowed at least one books from Library1 or Library 2

Tags: mysql, laravel, count, union, union-all

I need to count the total number of students who Borrowed at least 1 book from Library1 OR Library2.

```
Students table: 

id | name
---------
1     A
2     B
3     C
4     D
5     E

Library1 table:

id | student_id | book_id
-------------------------
1      1           2
2      1           3
3      2           3

Library2 table:

id | student_id | book_id
-------------------------
1      3           2
2      1           1
3      2           2
```

From the above tables Expected result Total = 3

Help me to solve this using Laravel DB query or MySQL.

Comment: What have you tried ? what issues you encountered ? what relations are in place in the Student model ? did you try whereHas and orWhereHas with those relations ? SO is not a code service provider, we can help if you start helping yourself.

Comment: Yes, I've tried using whereHas orWhereHas . But When I try to count 80k student data it takes 2-3 minutes.  So i decided to convert it into Db query.

Comment: can you add the code you tried that took 3 minutes for a count query to your question ?

Comment: The actual code is different than this. And tables are different. 
Btw. here is the actual code. https://codeshare.io/thesorwar

Comment: add it to your question [ask]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `UNION` (which removes duplicates) for the `student_id`s of both tables and aggregate:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
  SELECT student_id FROM Library1
  UNION
  SELECT student_id FROM Library2
) t
```

Or, `UNION ALL` (which returns duplicates) and count the distinct `student_id`s:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT student_id)
FROM (
  SELECT student_id FROM Library1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT student_id FROM Library2
) t
```